# Hot Module Reloading not working in macOS Catalina

Tags: webpack, macos-catalina

I upgraded to macOS Catalina. Since then Hot Module Replacement is not working in `create-react-app` as well as in an Angular app generated using the `ng` command. I did try to create a React app from scratch, but still Hot Module Replacement is not working.

What could be tha cause of this issue and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your node version, you should work on version 12 and higher.
For me, after i have upgraded my node version to 12.14.1, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your node.js to Catalina build. This fixes my problem.

Below is the command I used.

```
brew update node
```

Comment: Also add the steps you did to achieve that.

Comment: Yes could you please detail the steps you followed to update node js to Catalina build. I just updated node.js in a normal way and I still face the same issue.

Comment: For me, it started working better after moving from node 10 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project you may not be able to change the node version.

If you're 'stuck' using an old node version for a project in a Catalina environment, try these steps:

1. Move the project somewhere under your home directory (as opposed to in the root).
2. If the project is already in your home directory or you don't want to move it, add a poll to the ng serve command. For example `ng serve --poll 4000`.